# How can I implement this "Skip the port if it exceeds the timeout and move on to the next port" in python sockets?

Tags: python, python-sockets

So I am basically trying to write a simple banner grabber in python, which connects to a port, receives data and prints it. Now the issue I am facing is, the script connects to the port and moves on to the next port, without printing any data even if the port is open. Any idea of what I am doing wrong here ?

```py
# This is the function that i am using

#ip -> ip address
#initial -> initial port number
#final -> final port number
def grabbing_range(ip,initial,final):
    for i in range(int(initial),int(final)):
        try:
            print("Port :",i)
            s=socket.socket()
            s.settimeout(2)
            s.connect((ip,i))
            banner=s.recv(1024)
            banner = banner.decode("UTF-8")
            print("[*]",ip,":",port,":",banner)
        except:
            continue
        s.close()
```

Output:

```py
Port : 1
Port : 2
Port : 3
Port : 4
Port : 5
Port : 6
Port : 7
Port : 8
Port : 9
Port : 10
Port : 11
Port : 12
Port : 13
Port : 14
Port : 15
Port : 16
Port : 17
Port : 18
Port : 19
Port : 20
Port : 21
Port : 22
Port : 23
```

Comment: What exceptions do you get? Are they different in the port open and port closed cases? Try `except Exception as e: print e; continue`

Comment: @MagnusReftel thanks for the reply, I used your provided snippet to see what was actually going on, so basically I was using an undefined variable *port* in`print("[*]",ip,":",port,":",banner)` because of which it wasn't showing anything even if the port was open.